# Notepad++ How do I delete in between characters?

Tags: notepad++, characters

How do I select in between characters?

Turn this.

> 11144552222/**questions**/ask

Into this.

> 11144552222//ask

Comment: Your title says "delete", the body of the questions says "select". Please [edit] your question and clarify what you mean.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this throughout an entire document?

Comment: Do you want to delete everything that appears between two slashes? Only if it includes no spaces? Just after the second slash? Only after a number followed by a slash? It's not entirely clear what you want. Providing a few examples and brief explanation of what you'd like to achieve will help you get the most useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Double-click the word **questions** to select only that word - then simply press <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete it.

If you want to do it for an entire document, you can use a regular expression to achieve the result you want:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the Replace dialog
2. Enter `/.*/`<sup>**1**</sup> in the Find what textbox and enter `//` in the Replace with textbox just below
3. Select Regular expression under Search Mode. Make sure . matches newline is not checked.

<sup>**1**</sup>If your input string contains more than two slashes, you may want to use either `/.*?/` or `/[^/]+/` instead, depending on which result you want.

[image]

Comment: I think he is saying he wants to do this multiple times in an entire document. The solution you gave is well....obvious.

Comment: To be safe you should use `/.*?/` (non-greedy match) to avoid issues when if  the lines contain 3 `/` characters.

Comment: Or /[^/]+/ will also accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I've updated my answer accordingly.